# Pygame class coordinates (position) and animation (pyganim)

Tags: python, class, animation, pygame, sprite

Soooo I'm programming a game. I got a problem and can't find out the answer for two-three days now :/

My problem is that I'm trying to apply an animations BUT I can't get the coordinates or position (x, y) for my Player class...

My player code: (Sry for bad spaces, pasted directly from my .py file :/)

```
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    Entity.__init__(self)
    self.xvel = 0
    self.yvel = 0
    self.onGround = False
    self.image = Surface = pygame.image.load("PlayerModels\Sprites\PlayerStill.gif")
    self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 55)

def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
    if up:
        # Pasokti tik ant zemes
        if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10
    if down:
        pass
    if running:
        self.xvel = 12
    if left:
        self.xvel = -5
    if right:
        self.xvel = 5
        BegimoAnim.play()
    if not self.onGround:
        # gravitacija + acceleracija
        self.yvel += 0.3
        # Max kritimo greitis
        if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
    if not(left or right):
        self.xvel = 0
    # Prieaugis X direkcijoje
    self.rect.left += self.xvel
    # daryti X axis collision
    self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
    # Prieaugis Y direkcijoje
    self.rect.top += self.yvel
    # Ar ore?
    self.onGround = False;
    # daryti Y axis collision
    self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)



def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
    for p in platforms:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
            if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
            if xvel > 0:
                self.rect.right = p.rect.left

            if xvel < 0:
                self.rect.left = p.rect.right

            if yvel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                self.onGround = True
                self.yvel = 0
            if yvel < 0:
                self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
```

and I need help here in blitting (BTW should I blit?):

```
    for y in range(32):
        for x in range(32):
            screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

    camera.update(player)


    player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)
    for e in entities:
        screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        BegimoAnim.blit(screen, (xPlayer, yPlayer)) #help in here, how to?? (BegimoAnim means RunningAnim)


    pygame.display.update()
```

EDIT: tell me if You need me to add other parts of my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after exploring my code more and trying to do variuos coding stuff to find fix for my problem I found that I had made a pygame player value that has position...